# Wordpress importer / problem with images

Tags: xml

i'm experiencing problem with WordPress importer.

If I generate XML within my current wp, and import it to other site it doesn't get images.
All links are working fine,all details are there, but images are missing in upload folder.

If I use Theme testing unit (xml), its working perfectly. 
Any solution, ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest importing xml file clicking don't import images and attachments.  Then simply copying uploads folder from old site to new site. This is how I do and it always works without problems for even bigger websites.

Comment: @moshin , thank you for suggestion.
i can't use this solution. 
i've developed wp template, and i need option that will allow  users to add demo content  :)